# Is there a way to get the ids of the inserted records when using Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment

Tags: deployment, custom-metadata, asynchronous

I was going through the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm) and I saw this example

```
  public void updateAndDeployMetadata() {
    // Setup custom metadata to be created in the subscriber org.
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
    customMetadata.fullName = 'ISVNamespace__MetadataTypeName.MetadataRecordName';
 
    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
    customField.field = 'customField__c';
    customField.value = 'New value';
 
    customMetadata.values.add(customField);
 
    Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
    mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
 
    // Setup deploy callback, MyDeployCallback implements
    // the Metadata.DeployCallback interface (code for
    // this class not shown in this example)
    MyDeployCallback callback = new MyDeployCallback();
 
    // Enqueue custom metadata deployment
    Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
  }
```

`MyDeployCallback`  inherits from `Metadata.DeployCallback` so it receives `Metadata.DeployResult` and `Metadata.DeployCallbackContext` values in its `handleResult` method. Is there a way, in the callback, to get the ids of the freshly inserted custom metadata records? I was looking at the `Metadata.DeployCallbackContext` class but it only has 2 methods `clone()` and `getCallbackJobId()`. Can I use the jobId to retrieve the ids somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deployResult.details.componentSuccesses is a list of DeployMessages. Each DeployMessage has an id field, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this input!